# Git script to pull a set of repositories

Tags: git

I'm using msysgit as my git client in windows platform. I've a set of dependent repositories to work in my project.

Is it possible to write some kind of script to pull the latest for all the repositories. Now I've to go through all the repositories and pull individually.

Thank you.

Comment: By dependedent repositories, do you mean git-submodules?

Comment: No my work repositories like my git hub public repositories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in a file, say `pullall.sh`:

```
for i in "$@"; do
    git pull "$i"
done
```

Call as `bash pullall origin github gitorious whatever` from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does it actually do? Which script language is this? Where can I find some more details about this?

Comment: This is a Unix shell script. MSYS can run these on Windows. I'm not familiar with Windows scripts (batch files), but the gist is: loop over the command line arguments and run `git pull` on each of them.

Comment: What does `$@` means? Can I keep it in a file like a bat file and run it using the `git bash` from msysgit?

Comment: `$@` is the command line arguments. Don't put this in a `.bat`, that'll confuse Windows. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [`mr`](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/mr/) was design just for that, to automate working with multiple repositories. In addition to git it supports subversion, cvs, mercurial, bzr, darcs, cvs, and fossil.

Comment: Indeed, just uncertain whether it can be made to work under MSYS on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use Git Modules. It is super cool, you can have dependent repositories for your projects. To do this:

1. Create a .gitmodules file
2. Add sections

> ```
> [submodule "libfoo"]
> path = include/foo
> url = git://foo.com/git/lib.git
> ```

The docs are located in:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitmodules.html

And you can follow this tutorial:
https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial

Comment: Easier to use `git submodule add` rather than editing .gitmodules by hand. Also, he wants to pull all his repositories from GitHub, not sub modules of a project (see the comments under the question)